# Am I allowed to fire DoExpressCheckoutPayment automatically for PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal

My client wants us to automatically return the user to PayPal during the Express Checkout process, effectively clicking the "confirm and pay" button at the review stage if the transaction price has not changed during the process.

I can do this, but I am wondering if it is against the PayPal terms of service as it seems to me that this could be used to trick the user into paying more than they are expecting.

I have searched on the PayPal site and had a Google, but found nothing saying it is against their terms. Does anyone else do this or know whether it's acceptable practise?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want to change the amount in the DO Express API call against the amount that you specified in SET EXPRESS API call . Yes you can change the amount in the Do Express API call because most of the time Merchant needs the shipping address information from the buyer's PayPal account. And once they get the shipping address via the Get Express Checkout API call ,shipping fee is added to the authorized amount and then DO Express API is called .

Answer (score 0):

That is just fine yes, and for those instances you should set useraction=commit in your redirect URL to PayPal.  This will make the button on the PayPal review page say "Pay" instead of "Continue" so the user knows that is the final review.  Then back on your site you can make the call to DECP and simply display the final receipt / thank you page when that's done.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the useraction=commit parameter.  However, it's possible that the user's address will affect the price of delivery, so they need to come back to our site to confirm the price.  If the price has not changed, though, our customer wants the user automatically redirected back to PayPal (through a call to DECP).  It just seems to me that this process is open to abuse and we could change the price to thousands of pounds and the user wouldn't have chance to confirm it.

Comment: You'll just have to setup logic to handle all of that accordingly.  Based on the product(s) in the cart you should know if you'll need to add shipping/tax to the order.  If not, go ahead and use the useraction parameter to provide a "Pay" experience, then run DECP and send the user straight to complete page.  If you do need to add shipping, tax, then don't use the useraction option, and go ahead and display a final review prior to calling DECP.  Sounds like you knew all of that, but yeah, that flow would be perfectly fine.  If you abused it you would get lots of disputes and they would kill it